# Convert two first order ODEs into second order ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble expressing two first order ODEs as a second order ODE. any tips?

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}-1.005&-0.266\\ -0.1498&0.2005\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

with $dx/dt = Ax$ and $x(0) = x_0 = $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Namely, I know I have to take the derivative of one equation and substitute into another - but taking the derivative of one equation just leaves me with a constant. Can someone lay out a couple of steps for me to start?

Update:

I have worked through the algebra to come up with the following expression. My question is - did we create a second order ODE out of our initial ODEs? I am just trying conceptually understand the question.

$$\frac{dx_2}{dt}=-1.005\frac{dx_1}{dt}+0.0399217x_1-0.20037(\frac{dx_1}{dt}+1.005x_1) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}  \textrm{,}  $$
so
$$  \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1.005 x_1 - 0.266 x_2 \\ -0.1498 x_1 + 0.2005 x_2 \end{pmatrix}  \textrm{,}  $$
which it might help to see as
$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = -1.005 x_1 - 0.266 x_2 \\  
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}  = -0.1498 x_1 + 0.2005 x_2 \end{matrix} \right.  \text{.}
$$
Eliminating $x_2$ between these, we obtain 
$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = -1.005 x_1 - 0.266 x_2 \\  
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}  = -0.1498 x_1 + 0.2005 \frac{1}{-0.266} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} + 1.005 x_1\right)  \end{matrix} \right.  \text{.}
$$
Differentiating the first with respect to $t$,
$$
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_1}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -1.005 \frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} - 0.266 \frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t} \\  
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_2}{\mathrm{d}t}  = -0.1498 x_1 + 0.2005 \frac{1}{-0.266} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x_1}{\mathrm{d}t} + 1.005 x_1\right)  \end{matrix} \right.  \text{.}
$$
Then substitute the second into the first to remove all mentions of $x_2$.

Comment: Thank you! But why do you use dx1/dt and not just the constants, 1 and -2?

Comment: @user9858 : You want a second order ODE.  There must be derivatives.

Comment: Ahhh ok got it, thank you.

Comment: @user9858 : Alternatively, you want an equation that is true at points other than the initial point, so don't specialize too early.

Comment: In this case, are we actively trying to solve $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Or simply having a long expression the equivalent of expressing both ODEs as a second order?

Comment: In the given problem statement, that is a way to proceed.  We have replaced the coupled pair of first order ODEs with a single second order ODE having constant coefficients, so we may use "simple" techniques to acquire a solution.

Comment: I modified the question to come up with an expression as you suggested, would you be able to take a look? thank you so much.